# Python integration of large array of coefficient

Tags: python

I'm trying to optimize simple integration in python which looks something like

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import kv
import time
#Example function 
def integrand(x, a, b, c):
    return a * (x ** (-b)) * (np.sqrt(x ** (c) + 1) - 1)
#Real Function that I want to calculate
def Bes(xx):
    return integrate.quad(lambda x: kv(5./3.,x), xx,np.inf)
def F(x,a,b,c,d,e,f):
    zx = 1/((x**2.+1)*a)
    feq = e*x**(f)
    if (x>c):
       feq *= c/x * np.exp(-(x/d)**2.)
    return b*Bes(zx)*feq*x**2.
start = time.time()
array_length = 10
a = np.random.rand(array_length)+3.
b = np.random.rand(array_length)+1.
c = np.random.rand(array_length)
d = (np.random.rand(array_length)+1)*100.
e = np.random.rand(array_length)*100.
f = np.random.rand(array_length)
inte = np.array([])
for i in range(array_length):
    result = integrate.quad(lambda x: F(x, a[i], b[i], c[i],d[i],e[i],f[i]),0.01,100000.)
    inte = np.append(inte,result[0])
print("For array length = %i" % array_length)
print("Time = %.2f [sec]" %(time.time()-start))
```

But the problems that I'm facing are

- a, b, c are array with length > 10^7 (same length)
- integration range of x starts at 0.01 and extends to infinite
- Integration at the small x (like [0.01, 1]) is very important and needs small step.

I want to integrate this function on each coefficient value and returns the entire array of integration as the result (length ~ 10^7), efficiently.

What kind of tools should I use?

(+) I just changed my code from simple example to actual integration form that I need to solve. Sorry for making confusion.

Comment: Did you mean `numpy` instead of `bumpy`? ...

Comment: Please see how to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can better understand what your inputs are

Comment: Haha yes it was numpy sorry

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the values for b and c as well as the real x starting point? If x starts at 0 there is a "nice" convergent integral in my answer. If not, it may still be possible to handle analitically with a bounded integral from 0 to whatever the real bound is.

Comment: Sorry for late update. The coefficients in my example were not related to my original code for physical problem, so I forgot to set the example value.

Answer (score 2):

I suspected that this integral would converge for certain values of b and c, so I tried to evaluate this using Sympy:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

a, b, c = sympy.symbols('a, b, c', positive=True)

x = sympy.Symbol('x', positive=True)

sympy.integrate(a*(x**(-b))*(sympy.sqrt(x**c+1)-1), (x, 0, sympy.oo))
```

[image: integral result]

This means that you should be able to obtain the correct results with this code as long as your coefficients pass the check function.

```
from numpy import sqrt, pi

from scipy.special import gamma

def check(a, b, c):
    assert (-(-b + 1)/c < 1)
    assert (1/2 - (-b + 1)/c > 1)
    assert (1 - (-b + 1)/c > 1)

def result(a, b, c):
    return a*gamma(-b/c + 1 + 1/c)*gamma(b/c - 1/2 - 1/c)/(2*sqrt(pi)*(b - 1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing idea. But the code that I posted was simple example and actual integration is somewhat more complicated than it. Can this method applicable for all different cases of integration?

Comment: In general it is much faster to evaluate an expression than to do quadrature (numerical integration like you have in your code), so you should at least try to find an analytic integral before resorting to numerical methods. Also, as a general hint on Stack Overflow, it is usually best to start with a minimal version of your actual problem instead of a made up example, since this can be important to people trying to solve your problem. If you post your real equation I can have a look at it.